# How to perform this search results?

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc-3

I have one question about LINQ, I dont know how to get the result I need.

In my social network, I have the followers board, and I also have a search box to find the followers related by name or email.

My problem is, I dont know how to get this result. Having the Nickname or Email of the user, search the related followers.

This is my Followers table:

```
----------------------------
| ID | UserID | FollowerID |
----------------------------
```

My User table (only the columns I need)

```
-------------------------------------
| ID | Email | Nickname | Thumbnail |
-------------------------------------
```

My search box will be able to search results by Nickname or Email.

I tried to perform this query:

```
SELECT u.ID, u.Thumbnail, u.Nickname, u.Email
FROM dbo.[User] u
INNER JOIN dbo.Followers f
ON f.FollowerID = u.ID
WHERE f.UserID=4 and u.Nickname LIKE 'Laura'
ORDER BY u.Nickname
```

In this case, I would be UserID = 4, and I would be able to perform a search request of my followers...

Could anyone help me to perform this query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be you are looking for something like this.

Assuming that your search box contains the input `Laura`, I believe that you want to search the columns `NickName` and `Email` that contain the text `Laura`.

`LIKE '%Laura%'` would return rows containing the text *Laura* anywhere in the column.

`LIKE 'Laura%'` would return rows where the column text begins with text *Laura*.

Simply having `LIKE 'Laura'` would return only rows that exactly match the text *Laura*.

```
SELECT      u.ID
        ,   u.Thumbnail
        ,   u.Nickname
        ,   u.Email
FROM        dbo.[User]      u
INNER JOIN  dbo.Followers   f
ON          f.FollowerID    = u.ID
WHERE       f.UserID        = 4 
AND         (
                    u.Nickname  LIKE '%Laura%'
                OR  u.Email     LIKE '%Laura%'
            )
ORDER BY    u.Nickname
```

***Sample data:***

[image: Sample]

Comment: It doesnt bring me the result... I have UserID=4 in my Followers table, I have Laura, which UserID = 2 as FollowerID=2 in Followers table, and I have Nickname 'Laura' in my User table... so it should bring me the result `Laura`...

Comment: Thank you Siva, I was switching UserID and FollowerID in my Followers table.

Answer (score 0):

```
var results = from u in users 
              join f in followers on f.Userid equals u.id
              where u.Nickname.Contains('Laura') || u.Email.Contains('Laura') 
                    && f.UserID==4
              select new {ID = u.ID, 
                          Thumbnail = u.thumbnail, 
                          Nickname = u.Nickname, 
                          Email = u.Email }
```